# How to access class method from another class in flutter?

Tags: class, flutter, key, global

Hi guys im flutter and dart new-be

i make photoupload function

But I got into trouble while I was making it.

'class pictureBox()' can't recognize 'getImage()' ,,

Its my whole code :

```
class writeprofile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _writeprofileState createState() => _writeprofileState();
}

class _writeprofileState extends State<writeprofile> {
  File _image;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future getImage() async{
      var image= await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      setState(() {
        _image = image;
        print('Image Path $_image');
      });
    }

    Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async{
      String filName = basename(_image.path);
      StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filName);
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
      StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
      setState(() {
        print("Profile pic upload !!");
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Profile pic Upload !!')));
      });
    }


    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context)=> Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
                    child: Text(
                      '사진 선택',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 50),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 1,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4,
                      color: Colors.black26,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 15,
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: const Color.fromRGBO(250, 80, 120, 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(30)),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "가이드 라인을 읽어주세요 !",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        letterSpacing: 0.3,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        PictureBox(),
                        PictureBox(),
                        PictureBox(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        PictureBox(),
                        PictureBox(),
                        PictureBox(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: (){uploadPic(context);},
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /20,
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(250, 80, 100, 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(30)),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Next",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            letterSpacing: 0.3,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PictureBox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PictureBoxState createState() => _PictureBoxState();
}

class _PictureBoxState extends State<PictureBox>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){getImage(context);},
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          child:Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.3,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7,
            color: Colors.black12,
            child: Center(
              child: (_image!=null)? Image.file(_image, fit:BoxFit.fill)
                  :Icon(
                Icons.camera_alt,
                color: Colors.black26,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code , i want use to 'Future getImage()' in PictureBox How to running getImage() in PictureBox?

How can I get use getImage in class Picture?

I somewhat understand global key, I tried many ways but i still can't fix my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i have just adjusted your code. Also have a look on CamelCase Conventions for naming a class.

```html
class WriteProfile extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _WriteProfileState createState() => _WriteProfileState();
}

class _WriteProfileState extends State< WriteProfile > {
  File _image;

Future getImage(BuildContext context) async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      print('Image Path $_image');
    });
  }

Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {
    String filName = basename(_image.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    setState(() {
      print("Profile pic upload !!");
      Scaffold.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Profile pic Upload !!')));
    });
  }



 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
                    child: Text(
                      '사진 선택',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 50),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 1,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4,
                      color: Colors.black26,
                    ),
                  ),

                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 15,
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: const Color.fromRGBO(250, 80, 120, 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(30)),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "가이드 라인을 읽어주세요 !",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        letterSpacing: 0.3,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _buildPictureBox(),
                        _buildPictureBox(),
                        _buildPictureBox(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _buildPictureBox(),
                        _buildPictureBox(),
                        _buildPictureBox(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      uploadPic(context);
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(250, 80, 100, 1),
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(30)),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Next",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: const Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            letterSpacing: 0.3,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget _buildPictureBox() {
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          getImage(context);
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.3,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7,
            color: Colors.black12,
            child: Center(
              child: (_image != null)
                  ? Image.file(_image, fit: BoxFit.fill)
                  : Icon(
                      Icons.camera_alt,
                      color: Colors.black26,
                    ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, bottom: 30),
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                child: sampleImage == null
                    ? Container(
                        width: 150.0,
                        height: 150.0,
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(197, 214, 226, 1.0),
                                width: 3,
                                style: BorderStyle.solid),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  "images/profile.png",
                                ),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                colorFilter:
                                    ColorFilter.srgbToLinearGamma())))
                    : Container(
                        width: 150.0,
                        height: 150.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(197, 214, 226, 1.0),
                                width: 3,
                                style: BorderStyle.solid),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: FileImage(sampleImage),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            )),
                      )),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 25,
            right: 0,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              maxRadius: 25,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(197, 214, 226, 1.0),
                      width: 3,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid),
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.photo_camera,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                  hoverColor: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: () {
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                ListTile(
                                  title: Text('Camera'),
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                    var tempImage =
                                        await ImagePicker.pickImage(
                                            source: ImageSource.camera);

                                    setState(() {
                                      sampleImage = tempImage;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                ListTile(
                                  title: Text('Gallery'),
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                    var tempImage =
                                        await ImagePicker.pickImage(
                                            source: ImageSource.gallery);

                                    setState(() {
                                      sampleImage = tempImage;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

and please use below library depend on your requirement

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'util/CustomIcon.dart';
```

Upload image code

```
onTap: () async {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                        var tempImage =
                                            await ImagePicker.pickImage(
                                                source: ImageSource.gallery,
                                                imageQuality: 50);

                                        sampleImage = tempImage;
                                        StorageReference storageReference =
                                            FirebaseStorage.instance
                                                .ref()
                                                .child("Chatbox")
                                                .child(
                                                    "$userId${widget.name.userId}${DateTime.now()}");
                                        if (sampleImage != null) {
                                          // Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>PhotoFather(abc: tempImage,)));
                                          StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
                                              storageReference
                                                  .putFile(sampleImage);
```